# Entity Framework Large where statement with multiple value types

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am looking to implement a search feature into my server that uses Entity Framework, right now I have it working for searching on the fields I want aside from my birthdate field.

My where statement looks disgusting and is kinda meh, also I cannot seem to find the right way to `|` all my statements then require that if a date is being searched parse it correctly and use it.

When my search param is `"11/06/1996"` and I know there are a few records with the same DateTime as their birthdate.

Also is `.Contains()` the proper way to perform a `LIKE` statement in SQL?

Query:

```
var didParseDate = DateTime.TryParse(filter.SearchTag, out DateTime specialSearch);

                    var dateSearch = didParseDate ? specialSearch.ToString() : filter.SearchTag;

                    allCompanyRecords = DB.ClientMaster.GetCompanyRecords(_usersInCompany)
                        .Where(database=>
                               database.FirstName.Contains(filter.SearchTag)            |
                               database.LastName.Contains(filter.SearchTag)             |
                               database.MciNumber.ToString().Contains(filter.SearchTag) |
                               database.MaNumber.ToString().Contains(filter.SearchTag)  |
                               database.MiddleInitial.Contains(filter.SearchTag)        |
                               database.Address1.Contains(filter.SearchTag)             |
                               database.Address2.Contains(filter.SearchTag)             |
                               database.City.Contains(filter.SearchTag)                 |
                               database.State.ShortName .Contains(filter.SearchTag)     |
                               database.State.LongName.Contains(filter.SearchTag)       |
                               database.Gender.Name.Contains(filter.SearchTag)          |
                               ((didParseDate == true) && (database.Birthdate == specialSearch))
                               );
```

Comment: Shouldn't `|` should be `||`?

Comment: I always mix those up, I am not sure which one to use sometimes.

Comment: a single pipe can be used (in normal c# code) as a non-shortcut bool OR, or a bitwise OR between two int values.  Generally, use || unless you know you need the other one